# lodash: Merging is modifying the source argument?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following piece of code:

```js
  const _ = require('lodash')

  const obj1 = {
    get: () => 'hello from obj1'
  }
  const obj2 = _.merge(obj1, {
    get: (id) => id ? 'hello from obj2' : obj1.get()
  })
  console.assert(obj2.get() === 'hello from obj1')
```

If I call `obj2.get(3)` it returns `hello from obj2` as expected. But if I call `obj2.get()` it gets an infinite recursive call. Why? Why would `obj1.get()` trigger an infinite recursion since it just returns a string??

Comment: You probably didn't expect the fact the `_.merge` overwrites the properties of `obj1` and returns it, so `obj2` is the same as `obj1`; `console.log(obj1===obj2)`

Comment: Yup! That was it `_merge(_.clone(obj1)` solved it!

Comment: One way to avoid overwriting is to use an empty object as the target, that is the first argument in `merge`: `obj2 = _.merge({}, obj1, {get:....})`